# In ASP.NET, what's a good strategy for maintaining dynamically generated controls across Postbacks?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Although [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx) is a great article on handling dynamic controls in ASP.NET, I have an application where I cannot generate controls on PageLoad or PageInit. They are generated much later, after the user has input data. Is there a good strategy for maintaining dynamically generated controls when I cannot generate them during PageLoad or PageInit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Page_Load` will still fire "after the user has has input data". ASP.Net is stateless and the page is regenerated every time there is a postback. In order for controls to keep their states properly you need to make sure you recreate them again.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Page_Load` event is still firing.  You can assign the controls an ID so they can be properly re-created on postback.  If you do not assign controls an ID, they will get an automatically generated name.  This will cause the input values to be lost and also the viewstate will not work properly.

I asked a similar question that might be of help to you.

[Dynamic User Controls get and maintain values after postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428433/dynamic-user-controls-get-and-maintain-values-after-postbacks)