# How to save property of Code behind page in ASP.NET 4.0 (not use static)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

Now I have a change to build a web application in asp.net. The style of ASP.net brings me some weird. The hardest problem is that I couldn't save the value of variable after each PostBack event (when we click button). I've see one solution in the question [Dynamic User Controls get and maintain values after postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428433/dynamic-user-controls-get-and-maintain-values-after-postbacks)  but it just only familiar with the value which binding with controls.

Now I  think about 2 solutions:

1. Like the reference question above, I’ll unbind the data when the page PostBack. I’ll save a variable in a Session and in the UnBind method, I’ll reload to variable in session.
2. Use the ajax Button (not reload all pages): I really want to use this method, but it sounds very easy to be error. I feel very hard to use Ajax control in asp.net.

My code:

```
public class MainPage
{ 
    //variable 
    private List<string> lstName; 

    public MainPage()
    { 
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
           lstName = new List<string>(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What kind of data is it?  The best place to put it is probably in the database.

Comment: Post some code and it could be clearer what you are trying to achieve

Comment: ViewState should be keeping the data on postback unless you are overriding it on Page_Load or before?

Comment: Thank you here is the code (when I paste code in the question, but stackoverflow doesn't allow it, I feel very inconvinient when I can't post my code)

Public class MainPage{
//variable
Private List<string> lstName;
Public MainPage(){
If(!IsPostBack){
 lstName=new List<string>();
}
}
}

Comment: Now, the code is already inputed. Thank you, administrator :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I found a method to save property of Code Behind Page in ASP.NET 4.0.

That's use ViewState["variableName"] variable. When I need to save a property (e.x var ttsHandler), I save it: ViewState["ttsHandler"]=ttsHandler;

When I need to load its value, I have to type casting:

ttsHandler=(TTSHandler) ViewState["ttsHandler"];

But this solution still only useful with well-known Class type (string, int...) because it have to be Serializable. Unfortunately, some property I can't assign its Class Serializable.

Ex: I have to assign a MyThread class (subclass of System.Thread.Threading), and the debugger require project to Serializa System.Thread.Threading class, that's impossible.

Now I have to use another method, that's not so good, is using Session["var"] instead of ViewState. I'll try my best to handle this, and I'm very glad with your help.